# QTY Problem Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, addtocart

I have a product with with sizes 40 and 43 each with qty 1 available but when I try to an place order for qty=1 of that product it say please select qty min 1 and max 1000 even though the available qty is 1.

Link to the [Product](https://www.goharshad.af/gaam-black-high-ankle.html)

**Note:** When I clear the browser history I can add the product to the Cart but when I remove it from the Cart and try to add it again it gives the message please select qty min 1 and max 10000.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The link is not working

Comment: @Phil sorry for that, please check on this problem the is working now.

Answer (score 2):

If you check your javascript code there is condition like

```
if(eval(temp - curQty) < 0){
    re = 0;
    if ( manage_stock == 0 ){
     alert('Please, enter quantity  Min:'+minQty+' and  Max:'+maxQty);
     return false;
    }
    alert('Please, enter quantity  Min:'+minQty+' and Max:'+maxQty+' (Inventory:'+qtyStock_1+')');
    return false;
}
```

condition **temp - curQty < 0** is true so that error message display

you have to change this condition from **temp - curQty < 0** to temp - curQty < 1

maybe this will work for you or you can set dynamic value for < 1

Comment: Can you please tell me which JS file contains these lines of code?

Comment: this js code is in template (.phtml file ). i am not sure which phtml file but maybe it's locate in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/ addtocart.phtml you can find in directory for this code Please, enter quantity  Min:

Comment: just run "grep -r 'Please, enter quantity  Min' . -l " in webroot. It will output the file which contains this string. Good luck :)

Comment: @vaibhav ahalpara I have changed the value temp - curQty) < 0 to temp - curQty) < 1 but it did not work.

Comment: @vaibhav ahalpara This problem is only with configurable products.

Comment: if you can see there is many line with same code with different condition. i cant count value for temp and curQty variable. but you have change all condition i think temp - curQty) < -1 will work because temp - curQty = 0 why don't you just remove this condition and try again if qty is 1 then value of temp - curQty is 0 but if qty is 2 value of temp - curQty is -1 so static value will not work for temp - curQty) < 1

Comment: @vaibhav ahalpara I tried to set the value temp - curQty) < -1 and but it did not work, there is one point that when I clear the browser history I can add the item to Cart but when I remove it from the Cart and try to add it again it can not be added and displays that message.

Comment: yes i have seen that but with that script only you have to debug script to solve issue

Comment: @vaibhav ahalpara I have removed the below code which is checking for the product availability, Now it works fine but if I select a product with qty above the available qty it  does not notify the customer that item in the selected qty is unavailable. please have a look at the code below;

Answer (score 0):

```
        if ( manage_stock == 0 ){
            qtyStock = maxQty + 1;
        }
        if( minQty==''&&maxQty==''&&qtyStock=='' ){
            alert('Please, select item');
            return false;
        }
        if(eval(maxQty - qtyStock) < 0){
            temp = maxQty;
        }else{
            temp = qtyStock;
        }
        if(eval(temp - curQty) < 0){
            re = 0;
            if ( manage_stock == 0 ){
                alert('Please, enter quantity  Min:'+minQty+' and  Max:'+maxQty);
                return false;
            }
            alert('Please, enter quantity  Min:'+minQty+' and Max:'+maxQty+' (Inventory:'+qtyStock_1+')');
            return false;
        }
        if(eval(curQty - minQty) < 0){
            re = 0;
            if ( manage_stock == 0 ){
                alert('Please, enter quantity Min:'+minQty+' and Max:'+maxQty);
                return false;
            }               
            alert('Please, enter quantity Min:'+minQty+' and Max:'+maxQty+' (Inventory:'+qtyStock_1+')');
            return false;
        }
        if( $.session.get("session"+proId) != null && manage_stock == 1 ){
            cartQty = $.session.get("session"+proId);
            if(eval(maxQty - qtyStock) <= 0){
                temp = eval(maxQty-cartQty);
            }else{
                temp = eval(qtyStock-cartQty);
            }
            temp1 = eval(temp-curQty);
            if(temp1 < 0){
                re = 0;
                alert("Please, enter quantity Min:"+minQty+' and Max:'+maxQty+' (Inventory:'+qtyStock_1+')');
                return false;
            }
        }
```